# Can I use COUNTIF on two columns to compare values?

Tags: excel-formula

I have two columns in Excel, like this:

```
 A   B
0.5  0.4
0.6  0.59
0.1  0.2
0.3  0.29
```

I want to count how many of the values in B are less than their corresponding values in A. In this case, the answer is 3.

I can do this by adding an extra column, `B-A` and then doing `COUNTIF(RANGE, "<0")`, but I am wondering if there's a way to do it without adding an extra column.

I realize this is on the fringes of what one might consider programming, but hopefully it's just on the right side of the line, rather than the wrong side.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can be done using Excel array formulas. Try doing something like this:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A5 > B1:B5, 1, 0))
```

The very *very* **important** part, is to press `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER` instead of just `ENTER` when you finished inputting the formula. Otherwise it won't understand you want to treat the data as an array.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is something I **would** do with a program.

Create a macro to:

- insert column C.
- set range("cN").value to "=bN-aN" for all N where range("aN").value <> "".
- do your countif calculation and shove it into a cell (**not** column C).
- delete column C.

There may be an easier non-programming way but I don't know it (and then your question would be closed anyhow).

Answer (score 2):

Shalom's Arrayformula solution is really good, but I could not make it work with AND function embedded into IF, so I had to find another solution, and finally I have found it!

```
=ROWS(FILTER(A1:B4, A1:A4 > B1:B4))
```

This solves the original problem in the question. On the other hand, you can use multiple conditions, use the filtered range itself in other functions, if necessary.

(This is a Google Sheet solution, havn't tried it in Excel)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Hint: Add more conditions to the FILTER function by comma-separation, i.e. FILTER(A1:A4, A1:A4 > B1:B4, NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A4))

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, but it still involves 2 extra cells: DCOUNT.

The following is an example(insert into the specified cells the exact text after the colons):

A1:Condition

A2:=B4>A4

A3:A

B3:B

A4:700

B4:5000

A5:700

B5:600

A6:7000

B6:6000

A7:700

B7:701

Cell with count formula:=DCOUNT(A3:B7,"B",A1:A2)

Comment: Perfect -- that did the job. Thanks! I'd never come across DCOUNT before.

Comment: Sorry: I had accepted your answer, but actually scraimer's answer is a bit better for me.

Comment: I agree, array formulas are a neat thing to know!(I didn't knew about them until now).

Answer (score 0):

scraimer solution is ok. But for a fun,

You can also write a macro like the following and assign

```
=myOwnFunction(A1:A5,B1:B5)
```

this approach can be extended for any other logical function such as A * B + C < C + D * E etc....

```
Function myOwnFunction(R1 As Range, S1 As Range)

   Dim J As Integer

   Dim Size As Integer

   Dim myCount As Integer


   Size = R1.Cells.Count

   myCount = 0

       For J = 1 To Size

           If (R1.Cells(J) > S1.Cells(J)) Then

            myCount = myCount + 1

           End If

       Next J


    myOwnFunction = myCount

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use sumproduct.

```
=sumproduct(--(B:B>A:A))
```

Gives the correct answer of 3